# Identification needed on this plant with reddish stems

Tags: identification

I am needing an identification on this gem growing in Utah. I usually pull them up when they are little so I've never seen it grow this big.

I appreciate your help!
[image]

Comment: pretty sure there are no wild or feral Croton's kicking around utah... Have you ever let beets go to seed? maybe at the same time as chard?

Comment: as a followup... does it taste like spinach... I probably shouldn't recommend tasting unknown plants... but here we are...

Comment: kale or spinach?  hmm. My first impression was maybe a deformed beet green (or chard, as Grady Player says)   -- but it's not just on one leaf.... Those 3-fingered leaves are giving off an "inedible" vibe (at least to me.) Never personally seen Malabar spinach, but internet pictures have 1-part leaves. Very curious what this is.

Comment: Do you know if there are/were peonies in that area? That plant sure looks like a young peony. Has it gotten taller since you originally posted?

Answer (score 1):

i think its a malabar spinach?

Comment: it's not, the leaves are too far from the stem, and too many leaves

Comment: iiWqfie, welcome! I see you have taken the tour, but have you also checked our [help], especially [answer]? Why do you think this is Malabar spinach? How can a future reader identify it? A good answer explains with a bit of detail instead of giving just a statement. Perhaps you would like to [edit] your post?